# Creating multiple Azure VM's with Terraform causing issues with OS Disk

Tags: azure, terraform

First time asking questions here.

I'm trying to create multiple azure VM's in terraform using modules and the count function. The issue I seem to be having, is that when it comes to create the OS disk for the 2nd VM, it errors with:

```
* azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.0: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate:            
Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure:     
Service  returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="PropertyChangeNotAllowed" 
Message="Changing   property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed."   
Target="osDisk.name"
```

It's almost as if it's trying to use the same name as the first VM's OS disk. Anybody know how I can solve this.

Here is my code:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
  name                      = "${var.hostname}-nic"
  location                  = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${var.rg_name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${var.nsg_id}"
  count                     = "${var.vm_count}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.hostname}-ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet_id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.vm_pip.*.id[count.index]}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vm_pip" {
  name                         = "${var.hostname}-pip-${random_id.namegen.hex}"
  location                     = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${var.rg_name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  count                        = "${var.vm_count}"
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "managed_disk_data" {
  name                 = "${var.hostname}-${count.index + 1}-datadisk"
  location             = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.rg_name}"
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "${var.data_disk_size}"
  count                = "${var.vm_count}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "${var.hostname}-${count.index + 1}"
  location              = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${var.rg_name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.*.id[count.index]}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.vm_size}"
  depends_on            = ["azurerm_public_ip.vm_pip"]
  count                 = "${var.vm_count}"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    id = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-shared/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/xx-image-xx"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1${count.index}"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  # Optional data disks

  storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk_data.*.name[count.index]}"
    managed_disk_id = "${azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk_data.*.id[count.index]}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 0
    disk_size_gb    = "${azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk_data.*.disk_size_gb[count.index]}"
  }
```

Thanks very much

Comment: What is the output of `terraform plan` and `terraform version`?

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/956

Comment: Hi. Here is the output:
Terraform v0.11.7
+ provider.azurerm v1.9.0
+ provider.random v1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you want:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "server" {
  name                  = "server-${count.index}"
  count                 = "${var.instance_count}"
  …
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "server-${count.index}-os"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
}
```

… but it seems that's what you already are doing …

```
* azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.0: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate:            
Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure:     
Service  returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="PropertyChangeNotAllowed" 
Message="Changing   property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed."   
Target="osDisk.name"
```

the `.0` there indicates this is an error on your first VM.

Did you originally apply, then change the code around the disk name, then try to apply again? Delete the old resources first. *(thanks @QuentinMoss)*

EDIT: this terraform issue may apply to you: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/956

Comment: Thank you Mikey. The first VM creates no problem. As soon as it goes to create a 2nd is when it errors. I'll post the plan output in just a minute

Comment: Thanks MikeyB. The issue was because I had a VM already named the same thing from a previous test that was sitting in a failed state. Looks like Terraform was trying to change the name of the osDisk attached to that. Deleted it and all is well. Have a great day all. Steve